# Display all due dates for all Google Task lists in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-tasks

Google Calendar only marks the due dates present in the currently selected Task list. Can I make Google Calendar display all the due dates for all tasks in all task lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, and this is the one missing feature which has prevented me from committing to using GTasks.